# Java and MapStruct

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

How i can initialize List in field and add in this list some values?

```
    @Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface MapStructAdapter {

  @Mapping(source = "some", target = "some")
  @Mapping(expression = "java(new java.util.ArrayList<LegalEntity>())", target = "legalEntities")
  @Mapping(expression = "java(new my.some.package.LegalEntity())", target = "getLegalEntities().add()")
  @Mapping(source = "entityShortName", target = "legalEntities.legalEntity.shortName")
  Representative convert(Message message);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add your own conversion methods in a mapper.

https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#adding-custom-methods

Example,

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface MapStructAdapter {

    @Mapping(source = "some", target = "some")
    @Mapping(source = "entityShortName", target = "legalEntities")
    Representative convert(Message message);

    default List<LegalEntity> toLegalEntities(String entityShortName) {
        LegalEntity legalEntity = new LegalEntity();
        legalEntity.setShortName(entityShortName);
        return Collections.singletonList(legalEntity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Very complete answer (includes _link to docs_ and _sample code_)! Could you explain, **how the mapping knows** when to use the __custom method__ `toLegalEntities`. Is there any declaration or naming-convention in place?

Comment: Thank, this is a nice, if i have one field in LegalEntity, but if a have more, then one?
```@Mapping(source = "entityShortName", target = "legalEntities.legalEntity.shortName")
@Mapping(source = "entityLongName", target = "legalEntities.legalEntity.LongName")``` for example

Comment: @hc_dev, as far as I understand custom methods take precedence over implicit conversion and MapStruct find is by looking at method argument and return type.

Comment: @Petr, that would be easier if you posted the structure of your models. However, it seems a bit too complicated and probably the first you could do is reconsider the structure of your objects. I don't have the answer off the top of my head although I'm pretty sure MapStruct can do this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a (factory)method to your mapper. No argument and return the List. Can be a default method or a method in s class you @Mapper#uses